# Visual Studio compiling files not included in the solution

Tags: asp.net, compiler-errors, msbuild

I have a CMS soultion where the visual studio solution sits on top on the CMS on the file system. There are many file not included in the visual studio solution. When I try to compile, I get errors for .aspx files that are physically in the folder but not included in the solution. I am at a loss as to why this is happening. How can I prevent VS from trying to compile these?

**UPDATE**

There is not really a stack trace. Full error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The virtual path '/sitecore/shell/Applications/Analytics/ReportRunner/DateSelector.ascx' maps to another application, which is not allowed. KSCVCPII.Web    C:\temp\sitecore\shell\Applications\Analytics\ReportRunner\Report.aspx  5
```

Where the file Report.aspx exists on disk but is not included in the solution.

Comment: can you share stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure why this caused the problem but I had to turn off the MvcCompile setting in the csproj (Set MvcBuildViews to false):

```
<Target Name="MvcBuildViews" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='false'">
<AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(WebProjectOutputDir)" />
```